# How can I use wifi radio energy model?

Tags: ns-3

How can I use wifi radio energy model in ns3? This file is for control energy of nodes specially state of nodes include : 1) Tx 2) Rx 3) Idle 4) Sleep.

Answer (score 0):

the WifiRadioEnergyModel Class you mention is used to measure the energy consumption of WiFi nodes, based on the transitions of the radio state. According to the state, there is different energy consumption, and that is what is measured.

WifiRadioEnergyModel is used in the basic-energy-model-test.cc and rv-battery-model-test.cc in energy/examples folder.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. So ns3 can set state of nodes automatically. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, wifi states are controlled by the wifi model. See the documentation